# Generic method to update a field in database

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, jpa

I have a class that implement all my workflow method. At some pointing time, when the request is approved by the workflow, I need to update status in database. For this I need to call the respective service class to save the status. The following method is saving the status in db:

```
    public void changeStatus(String employeeNumber, String carid,String Status) throws Exception {
    Car car = carService.findCarByPrimaryKey(carid);
    car.setStatus(Status);
    carService.saveCarDetails(car);
}
```

I want to make this method generic since I don't have status for car only. I have to update status for different object depending from the application made. It can be for application for leave/parking...I can keep the field Status with the same name in all table. Please advise me how to proceed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure , what ORM you are using , like if *JPA* you are using , you can use `find()` with class name  and primary key as parameters.
May be you can try adding a parameter in `changeStatus()` as `Class class` and while calling this `changeStatus()` method pass the `class` variable by using `getClass()` and can perform actions basis of that in `changeStatus()`

Comment: I'm using hibernate and JPA. Can you please explain in detail? it's first time am going to write a generic method.